# T-SQL : delete certificate from OS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sign

During signing of a stored procedure, I backup a certificate to a file:

```
backup certificate c1 to file = 'c1.cer'
```

If I alter the procedure, it must be signed again. To do that in a more consistent way, after dropping the previous certificate, I want to also delete the file from the system (OS).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: From T-SQL? No.

Comment: it's a one time thing, so I can accept xp_cmdshell and other dangerous stuff

Comment: If it's a one time thing, why not navigate to the path and delete it.

Comment: navigating is easier said than done....

Comment: `exec xp_cmdshell 'del yourcertpath'` maybe?